# Need help reading data into a directed graph using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

This function loads a text file of URLs into a directed graph, however I keep getting error messages. I'm pretty new to programming

```
def load_graph(args):

    G = DiGraph()

    # Iterate through the file line by line
    for line in args.datafile:
        # And split each line into two URLs
        node, target = line.split()
        G.add_edges_from([node, target])

load_graph(args="school_web.txt")
```

error message:

```
load_graph(args="school_web.txt")
for line in args.datafile:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datafile'
```

Comment: where are you reading from the file ```school_web.txt```

Comment: In addition to the missing `open` of the file and the try to access `args.datafile`(which is not defined), you could probably simply use the [read_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html) method